Azure DataFactory DataFlow: Need to convert a JSON document from document per row to a single complex document
Currently using ADF to try and transform the schema of a JSON document in a Datalake to the schema need to load items into HubSpot. The issue I am running into is that the output schema is always document per row instead of a single document. I am using a DataFlow with DeriveColumn to define the schema.
Need to get this source format:
{"Id":"1000000000003919138","Version":0,"ContactKey":"148101","IsIndividual":true,"Name":"Margerie Bouvier Simpson","FirstName":"Margerie","LastName":"Simpson","MiddleName":"Bouvier","EmailAddresses":"","OtherAddresses":"","PhoneNumbers":"","Roles":122,"FaxNumbers":"","WebSites":"","RecordDate":"2024-04-12T18:34:07.019505+00:00"}
{"Id":"1000000000003919134","Version":0,"ContactKey":"148100","IsIndividual":true,"Name":"Homer J Simpson","FirstName":"Homer","LastName":"Simpson","MiddleName":"J","EmailAddresses":"","OtherAddresses":"","PhoneNumbers":"","Roles":122,"FaxNumbers":"","WebSites":"","RecordDate":"2024-04-12T18:34:07.007973+00:00"}

To this output format:
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "email": "fdsfds@fdsfds.com",
                "firstname": "Brenda",
                "lastname": "Wooster",
                "phone": "(123) 1232332",
                "company": "",
                "website": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "email": "",
                "firstname": "James",
                "lastname": "Kline",
                "phone": "",
                "company": "",
                "website": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}

Source Settings:

Sink Settings:




Take a source transformation with the source dataset.



Take the derived column transformation and give the expression to add all the columns from the source as a subcolumn under properties column.

Sample Expression in Derived column Transformation:
@(properties=@(Email=EmailAddresses,
        FirstName=FirstName,
        LastName=LastName,
        Phone=PhoneNumbers,
        WebSites=WebSites))


Take the aggregate transformation and do not group by any column. Add a new column input for aggregate and give the expression as collect(properties)



Take the sink transformation and set the format to JSON and set the file name to the desired output file name.


This approach should give the desired output JSON format.

That did it! Thanks. I knew I was missing a key piece here.

Great to know ,this solved
